# How to skew hexagonal tiles on an x,y graph, using bokeh HexTile

Tags: python, geometry, bokeh, hexagonal-tiles

I am trying to create a hexmap of the UK parliamentary constituencies in python using the HexTile feature of the Bokeh library. I am attempting to emulate the Leeds ODI hexmap (https://odileeds.org/projects/hexmaps/constituencies/) and have used the q r coordinate system as supplied in their downloadable .hexjson file.

However, my plot looks skewed.

I am aware that the q r coordinate system that us used in the Bokeh HexTile feature may be different from the one that is used by the Leeds ODI. Hence why I have inverted the r value as before this plotted at a strange angle.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot, LinearAxis, Grid, HoverTool
from bokeh.models.glyphs import HexTile
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/georgefry/Documents/data_science/uk_pol/hex_map/cons_hex_coords.csv')

df['r'] = df['r'] * -1

df['q'] = df['q']

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Code', '@code')])

plot = Plot(
    title=None, plot_width=300, plot_height=300,
    min_border=0, toolbar_location=None, tools=[hover])

glyph = HexTile(q="q", r="r", size=1, fill_color="#fb9a99", line_color="white")
plot.add_glyph(source, glyph)

xaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')

yaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(yaxis, 'left')

plot.add_layout(Grid(dimension=1, ticker=xaxis.ticker))
plot.add_layout(Grid(dimension=0, ticker=yaxis.ticker))

curdoc().add_root(plot)

show(plot)
```

I appreciate that this is as much a geometry problem as a Bokeh-specific problem. I am also aware that the solution would be found by progressively skewing everything below the origin on the y-axis to the left, and everything above to the right. However, I have tried a number of transformations but none of them produced the desired result.

The desired result is something similar to the Leeds ODI link.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this image from the Bokeh docs:

[image]

You can see the "q=0" axis goes up and to the left. There are unfortunately different conventions, and some systems have a "q=0" axis that goes up and to the *right*. I think to convert, you will need to *successively* add 1 to the q value for every row in your data i.e. `q+=1` for all the hexes in the first row, then `q+=2` for all the hexes in the second row, etc... including taking in to account and "missing" rows of data (though you don't appear to have any in your particular data set).

Assuming that works, please [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues), perhaps we can provide some sort of adapter for this situation.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it had something to do with this. Wouldn't it actually be r+=1 instead? As I need to skew things to the left and right rather than in the direction of the 'q' axis. Additionally, how do I write that in code? I am unsure of a way to access the row number.

Comment: Look at the `(q,r) = (0, -1)` red hex above. You want it to move one space the right. That is, to be at `(1,-1)`, which is the same as adding 1 to the `q` value. As for how to do it, you will need to go through all the values in `source.data['q']` and `source.data['r']`. Every distinct value of `r` corresponds to a "row". Starting with the lowest value of `r` you need to add N to each value of `q` at that `r`. (Where `N` gets bigger with each successive row)

Comment: Another approach might be to start earlier, with the DataFrame. You could potentially group by `r` then add the correct offset to the `q` values in each group. (My pandas is not proficient enough to do more than just suggest the idea)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think it will require me to manually edit the q values. I tried looking for a global transformation but I couldn't come up with one. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I tried a number of things and the following worked. I took the `r` values for each hex tile and mapped them onto a number that needed to be added to the `q` value using a dictionary. `{17:0, 16:1, 15:1, 15:2, 14:2, 13:3, 12:3, 11:4, 10:4, 9:5, 8:5, 7:6, 6:6, 5:7, 4:7, 3:8, 2:8, 1:9, 0:9, -1:10, -2:10, -3:11, -4:11, -5:12, -6:12, -7:13, -8:13, -9:14, -10:14, -11:15, -12:15, -13:16, -14:16, -15:17, -16:17, -17:18, -18:18, -19:19, -20:19, -21:20, -22:20, -23:21, -24:21, -25:22, -26:22, -27:23, -28:23}`